# OData Type Provider problem with Socrata hosted data sets

Tags: f#, odata, type-providers

I am trying to access Socrata (open government) data sets using the F# Type Provider for OData v2. Why does the Type Provider consistently fail on what looks like valid OData service? I've tried both their simple demo and more complicated data sets like https://data.edmonton.ca/OData.svc/q7d6-ambg

I am using a small fsx file with VS Code, though I've tried with a full blown project, too.

```
    #r "System.Data.Services.Client.dll"
    #r @"C:\Users\protium\.nuget\packages\fsharp.data.typeproviders\5.0.0.6\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"
    open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

    type Svc = ODataService<ServiceUri = @"https://sandbox.demo.socrata.com/OData.svc">
```

I should get back static types to access the service.

Instead, Intellisense gives me back `error 7001: Schema specified is not valid` but these OData providers work fine in Excel. Socrata allows either v4 or v2 of the OData standard.